# Getting open close for each day of the week separately

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to write down the open and close price of each day, namely I want to write it down day by day and hence that Monday will write down the open close for Monday into a var variable and Tuesday will write down the open close for Tuesday. I will then put these values into an array for each day, which I'm able to do, but I can't come up with a method to get this data efficiently. I've already tried various combinations with dayofweek, but I'm failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
indicator("Daily open/close arrays", overlay = false)

var float[] monday_opens =      array.new_float()
var float[] monday_closes =     array.new_float()
var float[] tuesday_opens =     array.new_float()
var float[] tuesday_closes =    array.new_float()
var float[] wednesday_opens =   array.new_float()
var float[] wednesday_closes =  array.new_float()
var float[] thursday_opens =    array.new_float()
var float[] thursday_closes =   array.new_float()
var float[] friday_opens =      array.new_float()
var float[] friday_closes =     array.new_float()
var float[] saturday_opens =    array.new_float()
var float[] saturday_closes =   array.new_float()
var float[] sunday_opens =      array.new_float()
var float[] sunday_closes =     array.new_float()

new_day = ta.change(dayofweek) != 0
eod = time_close == time_close("D") and barstate.isconfirmed

if new_day
    if dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
        array.unshift(monday_opens, open)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
        array.unshift(tuesday_opens, open)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
        array.unshift(wednesday_opens, open)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
        array.unshift(thursday_opens, open)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
        array.unshift(friday_opens, open)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.saturday
        array.unshift(saturday_opens, open)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday
        array.unshift(sunday_opens, open)

if eod
    if dayofweek == dayofweek.monday
        array.unshift(monday_closes, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday
        array.unshift(tuesday_closes, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.wednesday
        array.unshift(wednesday_closes, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday
        array.unshift(thursday_closes, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.friday
        array.unshift(friday_closes, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.saturday
        array.unshift(saturday_closes, close)
    else if dayofweek == dayofweek.sunday
        array.unshift(sunday_closes, close)
```

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have thought of this, I've already plotted it and it works like a charm. thank you very much!